# Alternatives to Kalmam Filter

Tags: arduino, kalman-filter, balance, filter

I am currently working on a self balancing robot project. I am going to use a MPU6050 to get data from both the accelerometer and the gyroscope. Since I need to get accurate data in a very small amount of data I need to filter the raw data I get. So many people have suggested me to use the Kalman Filter but I could not comprehend it (the maths behind it). Are there any other types of filters I can use in my project?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A complementary filter can sometimes be used in these situations.

Comment: So you've giving up one of the best filters (i.e. it is an **optimal** filter ) that ever been invented just because you don't understand its math?! I don't agree with your logic yet the math of Kalman is trivial. You don't need to understand its derivation though.

Comment: @CroCo you are right. But I just could not find a source that explains it well for me to comprehend. I have checked many websites. All I want to know is what I should do with the data I get from mpu.

Comment: Applied Optimal Estimation by Gelb is a good practical book.

Comment: @CroCo okay. I am going to try the Kalman filter. With my code, I get 3 values (Yaw, pitch, roll) from my MPU6050. Is it possible to apply the filter by using these 3 dependent variables only? (There is no GyroX GyroY GyroZ AccX AccY AccZ variables in my code. The MPU6050_6Axis_MotionApps20 library helps my with that.)

Comment: You don't need any sensor fusion algorithm if you have already the attitude from a sensor fusion library. The Kalman filter could be used, if you want to get (Yaw, Pitch, Roll) from (GyroX, GyroY, GyroZ, AccX, AccY, AccZ).

Comment: @HansPeterLoft oh really? Thanks! This made me happy because I do not have much time to spend time on filtering.

Comment: @Huzo if you already have data fusion library doing it for you, and you have a roll/pitch/yaw output, you simply close the loop on pitch with your motor driver.

Answer (score 5):

A good choice for sensor fusion with the MPU6050 is a second order complementary filter, which I used for the orientation estimation in a project. The complementary filter is computational cheap and so a good choice for a microcontroller. A paper about the implementation you can find here:

http://www.academia.edu/6261055/Complementary_Filter_Design_for_Angle_Estimation_using_MEMS_Accelerometer_and_Gyroscope

Answer (score 2):

Particle filters (epecially in [Monte Carlo localization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monte_Carlo_localization)) always seemed easy to intuitively understand to me. You basically simulate bunch of possible states of your robot, rank them with probabilities and occasionally you throw away the improbable ones.

There's obviously more to it (and more math), but this should be enough to make a small working test.

Comment: Will check it out!

Comment: are you saying that a particle filter should be used to estimate the pitch of the robot?

Comment: Should? No. It's just another tool. Particle filters _could_ be used to estimate it. They would likely end up slower than comparable Kalman filter, but they can handle more complicated inputs and are really dead simple to visualize.

Answer (score 1):

Check this website [pratical approach to kalman filter](http://blog.tkjelectronics.dk/2012/09/a-practical-approach-to-kalman-filter-and-how-to-implement-it/) it will give you a comprehensive description of kalman filter for a balancing robot (like yours) both theoritical and pratical (you have the code as well). And it runs on an Arduino !

Answer (score 1):

Want to get orientations from accelerometers and gyroscopes?

Use the [Madgwick filter](http://x-io.co.uk/open-source-imu-and-ahrs-algorithms/).

From the [paper](http://x-io.co.uk/res/doc/madgwick_internal_report.pdf), "Results indicate the filter achieves levels of accuracy exceeding that of the Kalman-based algorithm."

As @CroCo mentioned, the Kalman filter *is* the optimal estimator.... for a linear system signal in the presence of *zero-mean, Gaussian noise*. Accelerometers and gyroscopes have a non-zero bias, and they also experience bias drift which means that, even if you could measure and offset the bias, the bias isn't stable and changes over time.

The Madgwick filter is free, and even better, there are already efficient implementations of the filter already written in C, C#, and Matlab. You can learn the math if you want, but again the math has already been done and the finished product - the filter - is free to download and use.